# What is the correct approach for studying this function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = |\ln(x)| - \frac{1}{4x}$$

1) I have trouble when I see absolute values and I have to get the domain and differentiate.

2) Can you help me doing |\ln(x)| - \frac{1}{4x}$$ = 0 , So I can find the 3 solutions

Comment: Is that last term $\frac{1}{4x}$ or $\frac14x$?

Comment: you can divide your study in two domains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ln(x)$ is only defined on $(0,\infty)$. Moreover, it is non-negative on $[1, \infty)$ and negative on $(0,1)$. Thus a good way to look at the function would be the following $$f(x) = \begin{cases} -\ln(x) - \frac{1}{4x} & 0<x<1 \\ \ln(x) - \frac{1}{4x} & x \ge 1 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Why the $+$ in the second case?

Comment: @GFauxPas good catch, no plus sorry - just fixed it right now sorry about that

Comment: So , when i have to derivate it , I need to derivate both ?

Comment: @NPLS essentially yes -- the function is piecewise defined, so you have to differentiate it piecewise. Also notice that the derivative is not defined at $x=1$ -- this is because $\ln(1)=0$ and the derivative of the absolute value function is not defined at $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Ad 1).  The absolute value $|x|$ of $x$ is defined for all numbers by
$$|x|:=\sqrt{x^2}.$$
So $|x|$ may be differentiated except for $x=0$ and we have using the chain rule
$$|x|'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2}}\cdot2x=\frac{x}{|x|}.$$
In our case we have to check two conditions for $f$ to be *defined*: $\ln(x)$ is defined for positive $x$ and $1/4x$ is defined for $x\neq0$, in toto $x>0$. Hence the domain of $f$ is $]0,\infty[$.

Now $f$ is *differentiable* additionally if the argument of $|.|$ isn't zero, that is $\ln(x)$ must not be zero, that is $x\neq1$. So for $x\in ]0,\infty[\setminus\{1\}$ the function is differentiable and we have

$$f'(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{|\ln(x)|}\cdot\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}.$$

Ad 2). You will not find the zeroes of $f$ algebraically but only numerically.  The only zero of $f'$ instead is easily computable to be $x=1/4$.

PS: The other critical value of $f$ is of course $x=1$, where $f'$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of the function is given below. It is easy to see that at $x=1$, the derivative does not exist.
[image]